# OpenGL Creating Texture Cube from vectors

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a random noise texture cube for a sphere.

I have developed a class which generates a cube of noise. This cube is just a bunch of `float`s indicating the value for that pixel/trixel.

The following is the code I have, it's purpose is to generate a `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` and a sampler to go with it.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);
GLuint texture;
GLuint sampler;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glGenSamplers(1,&sampler);
glBindSampler(0,sampler);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

int width = noiseMap.GetWidth();
int height = noiseMap.GetHeight();
int depth = noiseMap.GetDepth();

std::vector<float> negativeX;
std::vector<float> positiveX;
std::vector<float> negativeY;
std::vector<float> positiveY;
std::vector<float> negativeZ;
std::vector<float> positiveZ;
for(int z = 0; z < depth; ++z)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        negativeX.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(0,y,z));
        positiveX.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(width-1,y,z));
    }
}
for(int z = 0; z < depth; ++z)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        negativeY.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(x,0,z));
        positiveY.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(x,height-1,z));
    }
}
for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        negativeZ.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(x,y,0));
        positiveZ.push_back(noiseMap.GetPixel(x,y,depth-1));
    }
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,positiveX.data());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,positiveY.data());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,positiveZ.data());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,negativeX.data());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,negativeY.data());
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,0,GL_RGBA8,width,height,0,GL_RED,GL_FLOAT,negativeZ.data());

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,0);
```

My goal is to use this as a diffuse texture. There's no issue with mapping this to a sphere or the associated shaders as they work when I use a `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` that I generate from files.

So I know the issue is in the above. I'm fairly certain the issue is with the format, or internalFormat that I'm using, but I can't see any issue. The `GetPixel` calls to the noiseMap are returning `float`s.

What I'm attempting to do is basically retrieve each "face" of my cube of noise and use each as one of the 6 textures for my cube.

The `GetPixel` calls would throw an `out_of_range` exception if the requested pixel was out of range.

The result I'm getting is a blank texture. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Do `width` and `height` have the same value?

Comment: They do.

I just found the problem anyway. The problem was my `noiseMap` values were not clamped from 0 to 1.0, but from 0 to 255, so that why it looked like there was no effect.